# What is "Navigation Bar" option on Unihertz Titan Pocket?

Tags: navigation-bar, power-options, unihertz

I have a Unihertz Titan Pocket, and when I hold the power button, I see an option for "Navigation bar".

I've pressed it many times, but I don't see what it does.  Does anyone know?

Comment: Please post a screen shot of that menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an Android 11, touchscreen phone with a keypad. Interesting design.

**Most probably it is for enabling/disabling the navigation bar** (on the touchscreen) since it already has keypad navigation buttons. Or it might be the opposite; maybe for disabling the keypad's navigation bar and just using the on-screen navigation. Just toggle it from the power menu and see which one gets disabled.

PS. The navigation bar is the bar containing back, recent, and home buttons or a pill-shaped gesture bar at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Now that you point that out, I see a line (perhaps stretched pill shape) at the bottom of most screens.  And that options turns it off.  But what is the point of that line (gesture bar)?

Comment: :) It basically is a type of navigation bar. You can see the same in iphones and many recently launched smartphones. For example.. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l3_u0KrSqt8